# Discover and filter bluetooth peripherals

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Using

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
```

I print out all nearby bluetooth devices, and an example output would be

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x2819241e0, identifier = CDF9E8B5-370B-A593-5AC5-F73E37BDC5C4, name = (null), state = disconnected>
```

I'm trying then to filter centralManager.scanForPeripherals() with this identifier:

```
let device = CBUUID(string: "CDF9E8B5-370B-A593-5AC5-F73E37BDC5C4")
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [device])
```

and I don't get anything back, concluding that this identifier is obviously NOT the service identifier I need.

How can I find the service identifiers of all my devices? Or use another way of filtering to only show what I'm looking to discover.

Comment: Your example is trying to use the *device identifier* to filter devices with certain *service identifiers*, and as you've discovered that won't work (device identifiers are unique, but many devices may provide the same service identifier). What are you trying to do - do you have a known service identifier that you need to use on appropriate devices, or are you trying to list all services for a certain device?

Comment: I ended up trying ones from the bluetooth spec, and 0x180A worked to filter my list to what I expected. But what I wanted to do was find all nearby devices and have them tell me what service identifiers they were using. I'm just experimenting with it... so not trying to do anything in particular.

Comment: You need to query each peripheral individually and call `discoverServices(nil)` on them (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518706-discoverservices). In the delegate method `peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:)` you could then print out all services provided by each peripheral. Note I've only done this for connected peripherals, so don't know if it works without connecting to each first. The usual way is to know which service you're looking for, and hence provide the initial filter.

Comment: Yeah, you need to connect to them before calling `discoverServices()`.